# Converting Input From TextField to A Double Random Generated Number [Java/JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

I'll let you see first the GUI for easy understanding
[image]

So that's my simple program. What the program lack is its functionalities.
Whenever  I click on Submit. There's must be a random number shown at the Console but there's some errors and I can't convert the
input in the TextField to a Random generated Number.

I got some errors like these.

[image]

and Here's my code

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene. Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

import static java.lang.Math.*;


public class Main extends Application {

    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Random Number Generator");
       HBox layout = new HBox();
       layout.setPadding(new Insets(25,12,15,20));
       layout.setSpacing(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 400, 80);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        TextField text = new TextField();
        text.setMinWidth(200);
        text.setMaxWidth(110);
        Button button = new Button("Submit");
        button.setOnAction(e -> RandGen(text, text.getText())); //Eventhandler
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText("From 0 to :");
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, text, button);
        primaryStage.show();


    }
    
    //start of functionalities
        private void RandGen(TextField input, String Message){

        
        try{
            double Random = Math.random(input.getText());
            System.out.println("The generated number from 0 to " + input.getText() +"is " + Random);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("'" + Message + "' is not a number");
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I just want my program to have an input the textfield and that will be used as
Math.Random(input.getText()) but has errors

Also here's my second try
[image]

But it gave me these error

[image]

## updated -> pasted my exact codes properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. I did not change too much of your code so you can understand.

**Updated**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene. Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        primaryStage.setTitle("Random Number Generator");
        HBox layout = new HBox();
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(25,12,15,20));
        layout.setSpacing(10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 400, 80);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        TextField text = new TextField();
        text.setMinWidth(200);
        text.setMaxWidth(110);
        Button button = new Button("Submit");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            RandGen(text, text.getText());
        }); //Eventhandler

        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText("From 0 to :");
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label, text, button);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    //start of functionalities
    private void RandGen(TextField input, String Message){

        Random rnd = new Random();

        try{
            double number = Double.parseDouble(Message);
            double rndNum = 0 + number * rnd.nextDouble();
//          input.setText(Double.toString(rndNum));
            input.setText(Double.valueOf(rndNum).toString());
//          System.out.println("The generated number from 0 to " + input.getText() +"is " + Random);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("'" + Message + "' is not a number");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, i really wonder why should i not use a math.random code for simplicity?(anyways, that code gives me errors).
Sir, after analyzing your code. i tried to use it but it gives one error only
it is : 
Error:(48, 50) java: double cannot be dereferenced.
the error refers to this code -> 
double rndNum = 0 + number * rnd.nextDouble();
there's only one error now sir. and also. I dont understand what will happen if it will be multiplied with rnd.nextDouble()

Comment: @jerome_mjt Try it now. So rnd.nextDouble() generates a number from 0-1; therefore, any number multiplied by it will be equal or smaller to the number.

Comment: i already tried it but gives me an error -> java: double cannot be dereferenced.. The error came from this code double rndNum = 0 + number * rnd.nextDouble();

Comment: @jerome_mjt Oh change 0 to 0.0 or get rid of the zero completely.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't even used "input". First create the Double number from "input"

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(input.getText());
```

then create your random number like this

```
Random r = new Random();
int Low = 10;
int High = 100;
int Result = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
```

Comment: delete that extra ")" after getText(). That's just a small error.